# Vba excel blank cells error handling

Tags: excel, vba

```
  Sub Remove_Deregistered()

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
For Each cel In .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D2").End(xlDown))
   If cel.Value Like "*Deregistered*" Then

       Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cel.Offset(, 10).Value
      cel.Resize(1, 1).ClearContents

      Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cel.Offset(, 11).Value
      cel.Resize(1, 1).ClearContents

   End If

 Next

Sheet2.Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("G2").End(xlDown).Offset(, -3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete


End With

End Sub
```

In the Sub above when the Range D2 doesnt have blank cells I am getting error in this line :

```
   Sheet2.Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("G2").End(xlDown).Offset(, -3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

How can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some error-handling code, e.g.:

```
BeginTry1:
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(.Range("D2"), _
                               .Range("G2").End(xlDown).Offset(, -3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

ErrHandler1:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can ignore the error like this

```
On Error Resume Next 

' your code that might give error here

If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Description  ' optional to print the error in the VBA Immediate window

On Error GoTo 0   ' optional to reset the error handling
```

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm